# Python __iter__ and __getattr__ behavior

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable

Trying to build something and found this odd behavior. I'm trying to build a class that I can call `dict` on

```
class Test1:
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([(a, a) for a in range(10)])

obj = Test1()
dict(obj)  # returns {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2 ...}
```

now in my use case the object has a `__getattr__` overload, which is where the problem comes in so

```
class Test2:
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([(a, a) for a in range(10)])

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        raise Exception(f"why are you calling me {attr}")

obj = Test2()
dict(obj)  # Exception: why are you calling me keys
```

The `dict` function is calling somewhere `self.keys` but obviously `Test1().keys` throws an `AttributeError` so it's being handed there somehow. How do I get `__iter__` and `__getattr__` to play nicely together. Or is there a better way of doing this?

Edit:

I guess raising an AttributeError works

```
class Test2:
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([(a, a) for a in range(10)])

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        raise AttributeError(f"why are you calling me {attr}")

obj = Test2()
dict(obj). # No Exception
```

Comment: `__getattr__` or `__setattr__`?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you came to the same conclusion I did.  That's not hacky, that's exactly the right solution.  If you need to provide some custom attributes, but you don't want to provide `keys`, this is how you'd do it.

Comment: Note that `dict(iterable, **kwarg)` that you are using here is a fallback *after* attempting `dict(mapping, **kwarg)`. If you want to satisfy the mapping protocol, then you should consider implementing a `keys` method and `__getitem__`, it's the more direct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually have to PROVIDE `.keys` (clearly, or your first example would have failed).  You just need to provide the right exception.  This works:

```
class Test2:
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([(a, a) for a in range(10)])

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'keys':
            raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object has no attribute {attr!r}")
        raise Exception(f"why are you calling me {attr}")

obj = Test2()
dict(obj)  # Exception: why are you calling me keys
```